# swift mailer not working

Tags: web, swiftmailer

i am using swift mailer to send emails to my company agents

here is my code

```
require_once 'Swift-5.0.1/lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the Transport

 $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('test.co.uk', 25);

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')

 ->setFrom(array('test@test.co.uk' => 'test'))

  ->setTo(array('test1247@test.com'=> 'A name'))

  ->setBody('Here is the message itself');

$numSent = $mailer->send($message);

printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);

if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures)) {

  echo "Failures:";

  print_r($failures);

} else {

    echo 'email sent successfully';
}
```

OUTPUT::

`Sent 0 messages Failures:Array ( [0] => test1247@yahoo.com )`

is there some thing wrong in my code ?

also want to know what are these 2  parameters in first line ?

`$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('test.co.uk', 25);`

is there should be the name of my webmail which will send the mail to the agents?

or domain has to me mention there?

changing 25 to other numbers throw error

Answer (score 2):

Check that you can telnet into `khyberexchange.co.uk` on port 25. This will check if the port is open and a service is running.

You might also need to authenticate to your mail server to be able to send email. [See here for more information](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html) (top box)

Comment: telnet ? didnt get u?

Comment: first i want to be sure that the two parameters i passed are fine i mean newInstance('Domain', port); ?
first parameter is to be domain i mean `khyberexchange.co.uk` or is it 
should be my webmail address?? `info@khyber.co.uk`?

Comment: First parameter should be the address of your mail server, the second parameter is the port it is running on. I've just connected to your server, it seems you need to authenticate before sending emails. Check out the link to the Swift Mailer docs I put in my answer on how to do this.

Comment: if i use server mail address as the first parameter>
it throws some error as:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host info@khyberexchange.co.uk [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0]' in /home/khybermo/public_html/cpanel/Swift-5.0.1/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:259 `

Comment: Mail server, not email address.

Comment: the server imm using for mail GOT u :)